# What is Preventing My Objective-C Class from Being Used in a Widget Extension?

Tags: widgetkit

Recently, I was tasked with preparing our mixed-language (Objective-C & Swift) iOS project for the implementation of a widget extension. Unfortunately, I continue to encounter errors that I don't know how to resolve.

I created the widget extension, and my first modification was to create a sample `TimelineEntry` by using one of the model objects (`Item`) from the application's main target:

```swift
struct SingleItemEntry: TimelineEntry {
    let date: Date
    let item: Item // Cannot find type 'Item' in scope
}
```

Since the model object is located within the main target, I located the type, and it's an Objective-C class. Our existing bridging header imports many `UIKit`-based view/view controller types that can't be used in a widget extension, so I created a second bridging header so that I can import the Objective-C types that the widget requires.

In the newly-created bridging header, I added the following import statement:

```swift
#import "Item.h"
```

In the Build Settings for the widget extension, I added the path to the newly-created bridging header, which is located in the main target, for the `Objective-C Bridging Header` setting.

When I try to build the project, I encounter a dozen errors within the widget extension. Following the errors, I am taken to `Item.h` in the main target. There, `UIKit`-based properties exist, which I plan to refactor in the future in order to remove user-interface-related properties from the model object. Some of the properties and errors are:

```swift
@property(copy, nonatomic) UIColor *itemColor; // Property with 'copy' attribute must be of object type
                                               // Unknown type name 'UIColor'


-(void)badgeBackgroundImage:(void(^)(UIImage * _Nullable badgeBackgroundImage, UIColor * _Nullable fillColor))block; // Unknown type name 'UIColor'
                                                                                                                     // Unknown type name 'UIImage'
```

If I'm not mistaken, `UIImage` and `UIColor` can be used within a widget extension, so I'm confused regarding how I can resolve the errors.

What am I overlooking or, likely, not understanding about my project's configuration that's causing the errors when attempting to use the `Item` model object in the widget extension?

Comment: Did you add Item.m and any related classes to the widget’s target? Does Item.h import UIKit?